# Conceptnet Numberbatch (multilingual) OOV words

Tags: python, word-embedding, conceptnet

I'm working on a text classification problem (on a French corpus) and I'm experimenting with different Word Embeddings. I was very interested in what ConceptNet has to offer so I decided to give it a shot.

I wasn't able to find a dedicated tutorial for my particular task, so I took the advice from their [blog](http://blog.conceptnet.io/word-embeddings/):

> How do I use ConceptNet Numberbatch?
>
> To make it as straightforward as possible:
>
> Work through any tutorial on machine learning for NLP that uses
> semantic vectors. Get to the part where they tell you to use word2vec.
> (A particularly enlightened tutorial may tell you to use GloVe 1.2.)
>
> Get the ConceptNet Numberbatch data, and use it instead. Get better
> results that also generalize to other languages.

Below you may find my approach (note that 'numberbatch.txt' is the file containing the recommended multilingual version: ConceptNet Numberbatch 19.08):

```
embeddings_index = dict()

f = open('numberbatch.txt')

for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()

print('Loaded %s word vectors.' % len(embeddings_index))
```

I started by testing whether a word exists:

```
word = 'fille'
missingWords = 0
if word not in embeddings_index:
    missingWords += 1
print(missingWords)
```

I found surprising that a simple word like '*fille*' (girl in French) is not found. I then created a function for printing all the OOV words from my corpus. I was even more surprised when analyzing the results: over 22k of the words weren't found (including words such as '*nous*'(we), '*être*'(to be), etc.).

I also tried the approach proposed on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet-numberbatch) for the OOV words (with the same result):

> Out-of-vocabulary strategy
>
> ConceptNet Numberbatch is evaluated with an out-of-vocabulary strategy
> that helps its performance in the  presence of unfamiliar words. The
> strategy is implemented in the ConceptNet code base.  It can be
> summarized as follows:
>
> Given an unknown word whose language is not English, try looking up
> the equivalently-spelled word in the  English embeddings (because
> English words tend to end up in text of all languages).
>
> Given an
> unknown word, remove a letter from the end, and see if that is a
> prefix of known words. If so,  average the embeddings of those known
> words.
>
> If the prefix is still unknown, continue removing letters from
> the end until a known prefix is found.  Give up when a single
> character remains.

Am I doing something wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you taking into account ConceptNet Numberbatch's format? As shown in the [project's GitHub](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet-numberbatch#downloads), it looks like this:

> /c/en/absolute_value -0.0847 -0.1316 -0.0800 -0.0708 -0.2514 -0.1687 -...
>
> /c/en/absolute_zero 0.0056 -0.0051 0.0332 -0.1525 -0.0955 -0.0902 0.07...

This format means that `fille` will not be found, but `/c/fr/fille` will.

Comment: Thank you! That was it, I don't know how I didn't see that before. Cheers!